# C# Create a list of objects from an 2 IEnumerable instances containing only those objects with a value found in the second list

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have 2 different classes:

```
public class ClassOne
{
    public string ClassOneID { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class ClassTwo
{
    public string ClassTwoID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I have `IEnumerable` instances of each. I want to return a `List<ClassOne>` that contains only the `ClassOne` items whose `ClassOneID` is equal to the `ClassTwoID` of a `ClassTwo` object from the second `IEnumerable` instance (if that makes sense!). I was thinking the following:

```
var list = new List<ClassOne>();
list.AddRange(classOneEnumerable.Where(o => 
                classTwoEnumerable.Select(c => c.ClassTwoID == o.ClassOneID).First()));
```

This logic is contained within code that is some days off building/testing, so I am not actually able to run it just yet. I am not sure if what I have come up with is actually correct, and was hoping someone could put me right if I am mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list = (from classOne in classOneEnumerable
            from classTwo in classTwoEnumerable
            where classOne.ClassOneID == classTwo.ClassTwoID
            select classOne).ToList();

var list2 = (from classOne in classOneEnumerable
             join classTwo in classTwoEnumerable
             on classOne.ClassOneID equals classTwo.ClassTwoID
             select classOne).ToList();
```

Both queries will yield the same results.

Comment: if you really need a `List` as the question currently asks, you'll also need to call `ToList()` on the result.

Answer (score 3):

The existing answers are fine if you can handle `O(n2)`.  Otherwise I would sort the inner values so that you can get `n log(n)` performance.

Comment: And using a hash based set can give you O(n) performance, and with noticeably simpler code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var list = classOneEnumerable.Where(o => classTwoEnumerable
                                  .Any(c => c.ClassTwoID == o.ClassOneID)))
                             .ToList();
```